# Redirect from webpages without modifying the app's code

Tags: android, ios, android-manifest, redirect, info.plist

Is there anyway to direct users to mobile applications without modifying the mobile application?

Comment: For Android, you should have at least URLs listed in manifest that the app can handle.

Comment: Is there any way to get the URL without asking the developers? Because one of my college tried to contact them but they haven't reply for days

Comment: It's not that hard it doesn't require coding. You can do it yourself.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini can you show me how? Every post i found requires to modify the manifest

Comment: Checkout my answer.

Comment: You are asking about deep  linking?

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J deep linking must configure in manifest right? I seeking for a way to not touch the manifest

Comment: you are asking without update any code in android project (without adding deeplinking code in android manifest or without implmenting deeplinking using navaigation api in android,etc).I think it is not possible in android

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J without adding deeplinking code in android manifest

Comment: @TanVeeHan without adding deeplinking code in android manifest or without using navigation api in android app .It is not possible to achieve in android.If there is any way means please let me know

Comment: i think you are trying to open a third pary app (not getting proper licence/rights from owner) from your web browser or web app or hybrid apps.? (or otherwise they dont implemented deep linking in their apps) so they you dont know the appropriate url or appropriate deep link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR iOS**

The answer is **YES**. you can open app without change the app's code. But It's not mean you can do it without change app's configuration.

There is **no public api** that you can use for this. 
But it's not so hard to make it available and if you just want to open the app, there is no coding required. Just a simple tag in info.plist do the trick:

[image]

Project -> Target -> Info -> URL Type -> URL Scheme = domain (could replace with anything you prefer)

Now application will open by calling `domain://` as link

**FOR Android**

There is a similar flow and you should add URLs list to app's **manifest** like this:

```
<intent-filter>
  ...
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

It might seem as though this supports only `https://www.example.com` and `app://open.my.app`. However, it actually supports those two, plus these: `app://www.example.com` and `https://open.my.app`.

you can read [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) for more details.

Comment: as per query/comments in question."Tan Vee Han " need to achieve without adding any code in android app (including in manifest also).So this solution for android is not suited

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J he mentioned in a comment that he wants to do this without developers. 
>> Is there any way to get the URL without asking the developers? Because one of my college tried to contact them but they haven't reply for days <<

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you need to add support for universal links. This requires access to:

1. Apple developer account
2. iOS app source code
3. Backend.

You can find detailed info in [this medium article about universal-links-in-ios](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272)

Comment: There is no need to access developer account.

Comment: You would need to enable associated domains for your app id, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes but no need for developer account access. ;)

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? How can you turn on associated domains feature for the app id without access to the developer account?

Comment: Associated domains is for map site to application. For opening app using custom url, there is no beed for associated domain config at all! A simple url scheme is enough.